# Flex Component for Country populated according to their States

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, mxml

i'm facing a big problem in Flex...

Actually My requirement is i have Two Combo boxes `Country` and `State`

when we select country According to States will be changed..

For example we select Country as `India` then State combobox giving all States in India..

Is their any Free components for this Help me ....

Big thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the two combo box is quite simple. You can use just one data provider and use the `selectedItem` properties from one combobox as data provider for the secondo one.

The problem could be find a list of all the contries and states.

This small example implements my solution.

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var stateCountr:ArrayCollection =new ArrayCollection( [
                {name:"United States",states:new ArrayCollection(["Illinois","California","Arkansas","Florida","Alabama","New Jersey"])},
                {name:"India",states:new ArrayCollection(["Punja","Uttar Pradesh","Kerala"])},
                {name:"EU",states:new ArrayCollection(["Italy","France","Germany"])}
            ]);
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <s:DropDownList id="country" labelField="name" dataProvider="{stateCountr}" >

        </s:DropDownList>
        <s:DropDownList id="state"  dataProvider="{country.selectedItem.states}">

        </s:DropDownList>

    </mx:VBox>
</s:Application>
```

You should also take a look at this [ComboBox State and Country](http://blog.shortfusion.com/index.cfm/2010/6/11/Flex-Country-Aware-States-ComboBox)